# Optimize reading of an excel file into a DataTable object

Tags: c#, excel, datatable

I use the below code to read data from an excel file into a DataTable object for further use. Since it processes from 100k to 500k entries, the reading can get a bit slow. Is there something I could change in my code in order to optimize the process ? Code is below.

```
 public static DataTable ReadAsDataTable(string filePath)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath, false))
        {
            WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
            IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>();
            string relationshipId = sheets.First().Id.Value;
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);
            Worksheet workSheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;
            SheetData sheetData = workSheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
            IEnumerable<Row> rows = sheetData.Descendants<Row>();

            foreach (Cell cell in rows.ElementAt(0))
            {
                dataTable.Columns.Add(GetCellValue(spreadSheetDocument, cell));
            }
            foreach (Row row in rows)
            {
                DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
                for (int i = 0; i < row.Descendants<Cell>().Count(); i++)
                {
                    dataRow[i] = GetCellValue(spreadSheetDocument, row.Descendants<Cell>().ElementAt(i));
                }
                dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
            }
        }
        dataTable.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
        return dataTable;
    }

    private static string GetCellValue(SpreadsheetDocument document, Cell cell)
    {
        SharedStringTablePart stringTablePart = document.WorkbookPart.SharedStringTablePart;
        string value = cell.CellValue.InnerXml;

        if (cell.DataType != null && cell.DataType.Value == CellValues.SharedString)
        {
            return stringTablePart.SharedStringTable.ChildElements[Int32.Parse(value)].InnerText;
        }
        else
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you thought about using OleDb to get the whole table like described in http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-excel-oledb.htm ? I think this could be much faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what's the compiler behavior on this or the performance characteristics of that API, but would it help if you call `row.Descendants<Cell>()` only once? It seems like something the compiler could optimize, but there may be side effects involved, so it doesn't do anything.

```
 foreach (Row row in rows)
 {
            var cells = row.Descendants<Cell>().ToArray();
            DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
            for (int i = 0; i < cells.Length; i++)
            {
                dataRow[i] = GetCellValue(spreadSheetDocument, cells[i]);
            }
            dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
 }
```